# How To use svn code base(custom extenstion) in hybris environment?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have hybris custom extension in svn and hybris package in local machine. I need to use svn custom extension so that i can commit my module changes/updates to svn server. How to edit custom extension path in localextensions.xml to use svn code with hybris package?

Comment: Just take the svn checkout of your custom folder inside \hybris\bin\ path. There must be config folder checkin in SVN. Then you have to take another config checkout inside \hybris path. And why you want to change the path in localextensions.xml file. Declaring `<extension name="youreextension"/>` is enough to add.

Comment: i will not be able to check out config and custom extension separately. setup is in such way, no permission to change the setup. So my plan is to keep extension out side the hybris package and refer the same in config which is present inside the package.

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is you want your extensions save in a different folder than say hybris/bin/myextensions, is this correct?

If so this is not a problem. To do this create your folder where you want to save your extensions, like you've said you have done. Open up your localextensions.xml in the config.

Include your extensions like this:

```html
<extension>
  
  <!--
    There should be a path dir defined within the config like below
  -->
  
  <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />
  
  <!--
    Navigate to where your extensions are defined, you can create your 
    own path variable above if you want too, this is just an example for you
  -->
  <extension name="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../myExtensionsFolder/extension1" />
  <extension name="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../myExtensionsFolder/extension2" />
  
</extension>
```

Once you build these extensions should be built too.